# No Post matches the given query

Tags: python, django, веб-программирование

Столкнулся с такой ошибкой

> Page not found (404)
> No Post matches the given query.

#urls.py

```
path('/systems', views.system_list, name='systems'),
path('/system/<int:pk>/', views.system_detail, name='system'),
```

#viwes.py

```
def system_list(request):
    systems = System.objects.all()
    return render(request,'systems/systems.html',{'systems': systems})

def system_detail(request, pk):
    system = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'systems/system.html', {'system': system})
```

Ответы которые я нашел сводились к тому,что важен порядок элементов в urls.py,но мне это не помогло.
Может ли это быть связанно с тем что в проекте pk используется несколько раз ?
спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Предполагаю, что опираясь на данную ошибку

> Page not found (404) No Post matches the given query.

И код views.py

```
def system_detail(request, pk):
    system = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'systems/system.html', {'system': system})
```

У вас отрабатывает **get_object_or_404** скорее всего по данному ключу, который вы передаете в запросе не информации в модели Post. Откройте админку и убедитесь, что модель Post:

1. Не пустая
2. По тому ключу, который вы запрашиваете есть информация.